# How do I perform a 3-way binding with UI-Grid and Firebase?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have an Angular UI grid filled with data that I pulled from Firebase. The grid table views perfectly with the $.asArray method with AngularFire, with the relevant code snippets as follows.

**The Html View:**

```
<!-- UI-Grid -->
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="ui-grid" ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-edit></div>
```

**The Controller View:**

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://commentme.firebaseio.com/comments");    

// create an AngularFire reference to the data
var sync = $firebase(ref);

// create a synchronized array for use in our HTML code
$scope.comments = sync.$asArray();

$scope.newComment = {text: '', date: ''};

// pushes data back to Firebase Array
$scope.addComment = function(){
  $scope.comments.$add($scope.newComment);           
  $scope.newComment = {text: '', date: ''};

// UI Grid Options  
$scope.gridOptions = {
  enableSorting: true,
  columnDefs: [
  { name: 'comments', field: 'text'},
  { name: 'date', field: 'date'}

  ],
  data: $scope.comments 
};
```

The problem however is when I make edits to the UI-Grid (using the ui.grid.edit module) those changes only can reflect on my DOM and cannot persist/3-way bind back to the Firebase backend.

I tried binding the ng-model and ng-change using the *editableCellTemplate* within *ColumnDefs* with a code like this but still could not get it working.

```
editableCellTemplate: '<input type="text" ng-model="text" ng-change="comments.$save(text)">
```

Would appreciate if anyone could show me how to perform a 3-way bind with Firebase if I make changes to the cells of the UI-Grid table, thanks!

**EDIT**

Thanks to Kato's suggestions, I have finally made the binding between UI-Grid and Firebase! The solution is as follows.

**The Html View:**

```
<!-- UI-Grid -->
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="ui-grid" ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-edit ui-grid-row-edit ui-grid-cellNav></div>
```

**The Controller View:**

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){

  //set gridApi on scope
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;                  
  gridApi.rowEdit.on.saveRow($scope, $scope.saveRow);
};

$scope.saveRow = function( rowEntity ) { 

  //Firebase save and promise return
  $scope.comments.$save(rowEntity).then(function(ref){
    ref = $scope.comments;   
  }); 

  // create a fake promise - normally you'd use the promise returned by $http or $resource
  var promise = $q.defer();
  $scope.gridApi.rowEdit.setSavePromise( $scope.gridApi.grid, rowEntity, promise.promise );

  // fake a delay of 1 seconds whilst the save occurs, return error if item is empty
  $interval( function() {
    if (rowEntity === '' ){
      promise.reject();
    } else {
        promise.resolve();
      }
    }, 1000, 1);      

};
```

I have used a fake promise as I am not sure how to bind the returned promise from Firebase to the setSavePromise method. A promise is needed as UI-Grid will not allow you to re-edit the cells without the promise returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ng-change is attempting to save a single string as a record. You can't arbitrarily pass any value into $save; it must be a row index or the row itself.

Looking at the [documentation for row editable](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/205_row_editable), it looks like you can trigger an event each time a row "saves". I'd recommend giving that document a heavy poring over.

Something similar to this should do the trick, since the saveRow observable will return whatever data object exists in that spreadsheet row (i.e. the record from $asArray):

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
  gridApi.rowEdit.on.saveRow($scope, $scope.saveRow);
};

$scope.saveRow = function(item) {
  $scope.comments.$save(item);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me the way! Would you happen to know how to bind Firebase's return promise to the setSavePromise method?